# how to append new rows at the top of existing .txt file?

Tags: perl, append

Hi I like to append new rows of data in existing `.txt` file. I use below script. It did append new rows but it appended at the bottom. I would like to append my new rows at the top of existing row. How can i do that?

```
my $filename = 'file.txt';
open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh  "-----------\n";
close $fh;
```

Comment: Small files or very large files?

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite the file. Changing the contents requires that the rest of the file, past the part that is being changed, be saved away first and then copied back after the new contents. (Since it is very rare that new contents has the same number of bytes as what it is replacing, unless we want to exactly overwrite single characters.) It is even more so with insertion -- we certainly cannot just add bytes in the middle, or at the beginning. The `>>` opens the file so that it is *appended* to, bytes added to the back of it.

For small enough files

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = 'file_to_prepend_to.txt';
my @lines_to_prepend = ("line 1", "line 2");

# slurp the whole file into a variable
my $filecont = do {
    local $/;
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
    <$fh>;
};

# open the file for writing, to overwrite
open my $fh, '>', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

# write new contents first
for my $line (@lines_to_prepend) {
    print $fh "$line\n";
}

# dump the old contents now
print $fh $filecont;
close $fh;
```

The `local $/` sets the input record separator to `undef` so that `<>` reads all the way to the end, and the whole file is returned as a string and assigned to a scalar.  Once that `do` block is done the filehandle is closed. Note the `\n` in the print, adding a newline -- if your lines-to-prepepnd already have it remove that.

For very large files you'd want to read line by line and write them out to a new file (to which you first wrote lines to prepend), then move that new file to overwrite the original one. It is a very good idea to make sure that the name for the temporary file cannot happen to match an existing file, for example by using the core [`File::Temp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) module.

Comment: @meemee  Great :).  Please let me know if more comment would be of any use.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the core module Tie::File to use a file as if it is an array.

Using a module for such a simple task might look like overkill, but Tie::File is very easy to use and you no longer have to worry about your files growing too large.

I usually do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my $file_name        = 'file_to_prepend_to.txt';
my @lines_to_prepend = ("Prepended line 1", "Prepended line 2");

my @file_as_array;

tie @file_as_array, 'Tie::File', $file_name or
  die "Unable to tie to file $file_name: $!\n";

unshift @file_as_array, @lines_to_prepend;

untie @file_as_array;
```